# Curved edge of a view

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm trying to use CardView whose bottom edge is curved like the below image. I don't want curved corners and just want bottom of card or any other View to be curved. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You probably want to use a custom view for this. It doesn't really look like a CardView anyway. Plus the curves from the CardView are always the same. Start here I guess https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html :)

Comment: Not CardView, any View in general. Thanks for the link, I'll try and let you know. :)

Comment: You need to create custom view with custom background, or with overridden onDraw method. @see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: You can simply use a 9 patch.

Comment: @Rotwang Actually the data in the view is coming dynamically.

Comment: This is irrelevant. You just want to draw (or simply display) a curved edge.